# How to get UTC time without date component?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, utc

How do I get the `UTC time` without any date component?

When I try to assign `Date.UtcNow` to a `Date` variable I get the following exception:

> Time value contains a date component which is not permitted

I am assigning `Date.UtcNow` to a `Date` property in a third-party DLL. I don't know whether it is an issue with different versions of .NET, or whether it is that the DLL was written in C# and I am using it in VB.NET. The only way I can get round it is to use `Date.UtcNow.ToString`.

Comment: I tried this,  Dim d As Date= Date.UtcNow, which worked.  Edit your post to show what is not working please.

Comment: @dbasnett: I am assigning `Date.UtcNow` to a `Date` property in a third-party DLL. I don't know whether it is an issue with different versions of .NET, or whether it is that the DLL was written in C# but I am using it in VB.NET. The only way I can get round it is to use `Date.UtcNow.ToString`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the time portion, you need to get the `TimeOfDay` property. It's a `TimeStamp`:

```
Dim currentTime As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dt As Date = Now.ToUniversalTime.ToShortTimeString
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: My environment is VS2010, VB.Net, Win 7 64, .Net 4 Client Profile, WinForm - works fine here. Code was copy/pasted from test program. 
 CDate() required if you are running under the handicap of Option Strict On. :)

Comment: Suspected as much.  However the Date still has the date component.

Comment: I guess you need to use some other data type besides Date. By definition a Date has a date component. I think you need to post the code you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided:

> Time value contains a date component which is not permitted

Is not a standard message from any exception in the .Net framework.  You said (in comments) that you are are using a third-party dll.  The exception is likely raised in that dll.

Without knowing more details about this dll, there's not a whole lot of advice I can offer.  I can make some assumptions though.  You said you are doing something like this:

```
thirdPartyObject.Date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString
```

If this is even *compiling* then the `Date` property on the object is not of type `DateTime`.  It is either a `string` or an `object`.

You also said you tried:

```
thirdPartyObject.Date = DateTime.UtcNow
```

If this compiles and throws the exception you mentioned, then it cannot be a `string`.  So I conclude that it must be of type `object`.

This is quite bizarre.  The third party object has a property of type `object` called `Date` that only wants a time?  Whomever designed this API must not have been thinking about usability!

As a super-wild-ass-guess, I would try something like this:

```
thirdPartyObject.Date = DateTime.MinValue + DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay
```

Or maybe it *does* want a string, then try:

```
thirdPartyObject.Date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

If you can clarify what third-party object you are using, or what it's API looks like for the `Date` property, then perhaps I can refine my answer.